# Sets of Object ecmascript 6 (es6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an Array of Objects in this form :

```
[
{id : #mixed char and num , title : #string },
{id : #mixed char and num , title : #string } ...]
```

I wanted to iterate through it and remove the duplicated object, i used Set structure to do so , but the problem is that Sets add operator will accept the duplicated object
I tried

```
let Unique = new Set([], X => x.id)
```

but wont help

Comment: Why don't you create an empty array and iterate through initial array adding only unique items to new array? You have to compare the items with your own comparison function because obj1 !== obj2 always.

Comment: @ViktorKireev this will work but I'm looking for smth to extend Set datastructure

Comment: Those are all different object references. A set looks at them as if they're unique. Set do not have a filter function as a second parameter I don't think there is a way to only use Sets for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) states,

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

If these are different object references, they won't be deduplicated. If objects need to be identified by `id` unique key, then `Set` is wrong choice. A map can serve this purpose:

```
new Map([
  [#mixed char and num, {id : #mixed char and num , title : #string }],
  ...
])
```

If objects don't contain anything but `id` and `title`, a map can be simplified to:

```
new Map([
  [#mixed char and num, #string],
  ...
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the duplicates with `.filter`

```
let uniqueArr = arr.filter((item, index) => {
    return arr.findIndex(item2 => item2.id === item.id) === index;
});
```

A fiddle demoing the concept: https://jsfiddle.net/4oanw972/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reduce` with `map` of `esmascript 6` and then pass the values to `Set` constructor. However you can use normal `Object` as well, `Object.values` in `es6`

```
new Set(arr.reduce((map,item)=>map.set(item.id, item), new Map()).values());
```

as you know you are identifing unique by `id` so just create a key with `id` pointing to the actual objects, hence the previous objects with the same id it will override and you will end up by having only one object against each `id`, then just get bthe values and construct your set.